# MS Access: Setting the .enabled and .allowedits property of a subform through VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking to create a single VBA sub procedure to change the `.enabled` and `.allowedit` properties of all subforms of multiple a main forms. The idea is that I have one sub procedure that can be called by a button on any form in my application.

Clicking the button sets the variable that I use to refer to whichever main form the button resides on. I currently have it working for the .enable portion, however I keep receiving an error regarding the .allowedits property. Below is the code that I use. The error that I get is

> Object doesn't support this property or method

It only occurs after the `.allowedits` line is run. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

cmdbutton_on_click_event

```
Private Sub cmdEditAll_Click()
strFormName = Me.Name

Call ToggleEdit

end sub
```

Called Subprocedure:

```
Option Compare Database
Public strFormName As String
Sub ToggleEdit()
Dim ctrlControl As Control


On Error GoTo err:
For Each ctrlControl In Forms(strFormName).Controls
    Debug.Print ctrlControl.Name
    If booEnabled = False Then
        Forms!frmfullcourseinfo.cmdEditAll.Caption = "Edit"
        Forms!frmfullcourseinfo.lblMode.Caption = "[Read Only]"
        If ctrlControl.ControlType = acTabCtl Or ctrlControl.Name = "Command9" Or ctrlControl.Name = "cmdeditall" Then
        Else
        ctrlControl.Enabled = False
        ctrlControl.AllowEdits = False
        End If

    Else
        Forms!frmfullcourseinfo.cmdEditAll.Caption = "Stop Edit"
        Forms!frmfullcourseinfo.lblMode.Caption = "[Edit Mode]"
        If ctrlControl.ControlType = acTabCtl Or ctrlControl.Name = "Command9" Or ctrlControl.Name = "cmdeditall" Then
        Else
        ctrlControl.Enabled = True
        ctrlControl.AllowEdits = True
        End If
    End If
Continue:
Next

booEnabled = Not (booEnabled)
Exit Sub
err:
    Debug.Print err.Description
    Resume Continue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I always give subform container control a name different from the object it holds, like ctrOrders. Subform container control does not have AllowEdits property, forms do, so have to reference the form object the container holds.

`Me.ctrOrders.Form.AllowEdits = False`

So this might work:

`ctrlControl.Form.AllowEdits = False`

Comment: Thank you, I will gave that a try in the morning when I am back at the office!